Property 'opacity' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'LoaderProps'
I am using TypeScript(tsx)
 import React from "react";

  interface LoaderProps {
   opacity: number;
  }

  const Loader: React.FC<LoaderProps> = ({ opacity }) => {
   return (
   <div className={`fixed top-0 bottom-0 left-0 right-0 flex 
    justify-center items-center bg-white bg-opacity-${opacity}`}>
</div>

and importing this to another file
import React from 'react';
import Loader from './Loader';

const Main: React.FC = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <Loader opacity={75} />
     </div>
   );
}

export default Main;

and this is giving me this error


TS2741: Property 'opacity' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'LoaderProps'.



Cannot reproduce: https://tsplay.dev/N97OJW

The error message you’re encountering indicates that the opacity property is missing in the component where you’re using the Loader component. Let’s make sure you’re passing the opacity prop correctly.
First, let’s check the Loader component:

what about the loader component? what about it should be checked?
